# Cannot swap values of nodes

Tags: c

i am trying to swap node values. There are no compilation errors. I am using visual basic for my programming.  If someone could point out where i am going wrong. Will be a great help.

Also, what could i add in my code, so swap any values, whether it being a char or int.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct lnode {
    int data;
    struct lnode* next;
};

void swapNodes(struct lnode* n1, struct lnode* n2);

int main()
{
    struct lnode nodeA, nodeB;
    nodeA.data = 1;
    nodeB.data = 2;

    swapNodes(&nodeA, &nodeB);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void swapNodes(struct lnode* n1, struct lnode* n2)
{
    struct lnode* temp;
    temp = n1->next;
    n1->next = n2;
    n2->next = temp;
    printf("nodeA= %d  nodeB= %d",n1->data,n2->data);
}
```

Comment: This is literally the 5th question today about pass-by-value vs. pass-by-pointer. Hint: you need to dereference the pointers in `swap()`.

Comment: You are using Visual Basic for C++ programming? How does that work? Or do you mean that you are using Visual *Studio*? Also, if you are using Visual Studio, you should learn how to use the debugger. It will quickly let you discover where the problem occurs and then you can figure out a way to fix it.

Comment: yes, i ment to say studio not basic lol ,sorry abt that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the swapNodes() function you shouldn't assign n1->next to temp; n1->next points to nothing.

```
temp = n1->next;
n1->next = n2;
n2->next = temp;
```

should be

```
temp = n1;
n1 = n2;
n2 = temp;
```

lnode->next has no role with swapping two nodes.

Answer (score 0):

In your `swapNodes` function, you are swapping the `next` values, it looks like you meant to swap data values, like this:

```
void swapNodes(struct lnode* n1, struct lnode* n2)
{
    int temp = n1->data;
    n1->data = n2->data;
    n2->data = temp;
    printf("nodeA= %d  nodeB= %d",n1->data,n2->data);
}
```

Comment: if you do n1->data, it dsnt work, it gives out an error, and you cannot use int temp for nodes, its a type mismatch.

Comment: I'm not doing `int temp` for nodes, I'm doing it for `node->data`, both of them are integers.